How to sum multiple columns using GROUPBY() function?
I have the following sample dataset.



Item
Value1
Value2




a
5
15


b
10
20


c
5
15


d
10
20


a
5
15


b
10
20


c
5
15


d
10
20


a
5
15


b
10
20


c
5
15


d
10
20



I want to sum column wise values based on unique items. So, my output will look like-



a
15
45




b
30
60


c
15
45


d
30
60



Currently I can achieve desired result by the following formula-
=LET(x,UNIQUE(B4:B15),HSTACK(x,SUMIFS(C4:C15,B4:B15,x),SUMIFS(D4:D15,B4:B15,x)))

Can I get same result by GROUPBY() function? =GROUPBY(B4:B15,C4:C15,SUM) this formula sum a single column.
Screenshot for better understanding.


I got the trick of GROUPBY() function. It supports to input multiple column range and SUM values for individuals columns by grouping items. The following formula solved my issue.
=GROUPBY(B3:B15,C3:D15,SUM,3)



Instead of Groupby you can use SUMIF,

In cell G4, enter: =UNIQUE(B4:B15), Extracts the unique items from the specified range.
In cell H4, enter: =SUMIF(B4:B15, G4, C4:C15), Sums the values in C4:C15 (Value1) where the corresponding value in B4:B15 (Item) matches the unique item in G4.
In cell I4, enter: =SUMIF(B4:B15, G4, D4:D15),
SUMIF(B4:B15, G4, D4:D15):
Drag these formulas down to fill the rows for each unique item



That i have already used and posted to my question. My question related particularly GROUPBY() function. Thanks.
